# Búsqueda dentro de Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un array, que dentro contiene datos en esquema json. El backend me otorga la información de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo deseo saber si este array contiene un Nombre en su interior. Lo estoy intentando así: `array.includes(_Nombre)`, *(siendo _Nombre un string)* pero solo me devuelve `false`.
Creo que debería hacer un bucle iterando dentro de dicho array, pero no estoy seguro de cómo realizarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes realizar ese tipo de busqudas con el metodo `find()` de javascript, este metodo busca coincidencias dentro  de colecciones iterables, y te devuelve el item encontrado

```js
let array = [
    { id:1,nombre: "pedro", apellido: "perez"},
    { id:2, nombre: "pablo", apellido: "pepito"}
    ];
    //Puedes usar distintas condiciones como: == , > , < , >=
    let existe = array.find(x=> x.nombre=="pedro")
    if(existe){
      console.log("pedro esta en la coleccion de datos")
      console.log(existe)//Resultado: { id:1 ,nombre: "pedro", apellido: "Perez"}
    }else{
      console.log("pedro NO esta en la coleccion de datos")
      console.log(existe)//Resultado:undefined
    }
```

Te dejo la documentacion de [find javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), espero te sirva

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es comprobar si alguno de los elementos del array contiene el nombre que buscas y obtener un resultado booleano puedes usar el método [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var data = [
  { name: 'Jesse' },
  { name: 'Mary' },
  { name: 'Will' },
];

var hasNameMary = data.some(function(item) {
  return item.name === 'Mary';
});

console.log(hasNameMary);
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es buscar un elemento que contenga ese nombre y a la vez obtener ese elemento como resultado puedes usar [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
var data = [
  { name: 'Jesse' },
  { name: 'Mary' },
  { name: 'Will' },
];

var mary = data.find(function(item) {
  return item.name === 'Mary';
});

console.log(mary);
```