# comparar elementos en un array

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, comparaciones

Estoy creando algo como un sistema de facturación y quiero agregar un botón para programar el procesamiento de cada producto. El producto debe ser procesado siempre y cuando no haya sido agregado previamente, pero no se como hacerlo exactamente

```
var productos=[]
productos= document.getElementByid("productos").value

    for (let i = 0; i < productos.lenght; i++) {
    
    }
```

mi idea era hacerlo algo asi pero me di cuenta que si comparo el arreglo con el mismo siempre me va a decir que ya esta registrado el producto y ahora no se que hacer

Comment: yo pregunte algo asi hace un tiempo, mira: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282378/como-saber-si-un-array-tiene-elementos-repetidos

Comment: tal vez te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/553091/b%c3%basqueda-dentro-de-array/553096#553096), usando `find` de javascript puedes buscar coincidencias dentro de un arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar la propiedad find del array, asi como en este ejemplo, espero que te ayude

```js
let productos = ["Producto 1"]

function myFunction(){
  $('#error').html('')
  const val = $('#producto').val()
  if(productos.find(e => e === val)){
    $('#error').html('Ya existe')
  }
  else{
    productos.push(val)
    $('#productos').append(`<li>
        ${val}
      </li>`)
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="producto"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
  Agregar
</button>
<p id="error"></p>

<ul id="productos">
  <li>Producto 1</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Esta pregunta se ha respondido en muchas ocasiones te recomiendo leer [answer], sobre todo la parte que dice: **No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que ya se han preguntado antes y se han contestado varias veces.**